# only 1 AT command sends (ESP8266/Arduino Uno)

Tags: arduino, server, at-command, esp8266

I'm facing problem with sending AT Commands using `Arduino Uno`. I've written a small program (link below) to set up a server. I need to send data to Atmega from my laptop using Wifi module `ESP8266`. Everything would be fine if the entire program would do at once at the moment I need to comment and uncomment (adding and removing double slashes) every line of AT code, because only one AT command executes in a single compilation.

It seems like the program gets stuck somewhere in the while-loop (even on the module, I can see that blue diode stops blinking). I think that I've done something wrong in code and I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial espmod(2, 3); 
void commands(String cmd, int waittime);

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    espmod.begin(9600);  
    while (!Serial) {;} 

    commands("AT+GMR\r\n", 1000);
    commands("AT+RST\r\n", 500);
    commands("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 500);
    commands("AT+CWJAP=\"SSID\",\"PASS\"\r\n", 4000);
    commands("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 500);
    commands("AT+CIPSERVER=1,333\r\n", 500);
    commands("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 500);
}

void loop() { // run over and over

}

void commands(String cmd, int waittime) {
    espmod.print(cmd);
    delay(waittime);
    while(espmod.available()) {
        char val = espmod.read();
        Serial.write(val);
    }
}
```

Here's the screen:

[image]

Version:

```
AT Version: 0.21.0.0
SDK Version: 0.9.5
```

Connections:

```
ESP    
VCC -- 3,3 V (external source)    
GND -- GND -- Arduino GND    
RX -- TX (Arduino pin 3)    
TX -- RX (Arduino pin 2)    
CH_PD -- 3,3 V     
RST -- 3,3 V
```

EDIT:

I've been fighting with this for couple of days, still without solution, but today it worked finally, but only once (after reseting power supply it's still the same) ! I could've seen all commands doing on SerialMonitor, so there is everything fine with code and i guess there is something wrong with esp module. As far as i can get only one AT command sent and executed in a single compilation, is it possible that 0,5 A current i provide to the module is not enough? Can module be out of the memory ? Is there any way to see SoftwareSerial monitor (is there anything like that)?

Comment: Can't you see your commands and responses via Serial Monitor of the Arduino ?

Comment: @cagdas I can see commands and responses but only generated by Arduino on Serial Monitor. I changed code and there is problem with AT commands and ESP for sure, because i changed atmega328p-pu to new one and even if i put AT command in loop function there does only first in a row when the other commands works fine [link](http://images82.fotosik.pl/202/037fbda5657d0249.png). Module works fine only connected via UART [link](http://images81.fotosik.pl/203/94e8e0e6b2503709.png).

Comment: you might want to check the voltage levels. esp is 3.3, megas are 5.0. Usually you can get away with the mismatch, but if one of your boards is a hair too sensitive or powerful, it might be enough to keep it from working. Since your software did work once as-is, i suspect hardware. a fancy level shifter or a dioide/5kOhm resistor instead of the esp's RX wire might help.

Comment: 0.5A, if it's solid, should be enough. try a 0.1u cleanup cap and a larger buffer cap (>333u) "shorting" the ESP's VCC+GND pins.also try +3.6V on the ESP, which might help it match up better with a 5v device.115200 is also pushing software serial hard; can you swap COMs?

Comment: ok, seems it's been working for a while. The problem was with voltage divider i used to lower voltage form arduino tx to rx (5v to around 3,3v), i used 4,7k and 10k resistors. I've changed it to 220 and 100 and it works ! i don't know for how long, but it seems to be ok now.

Comment: 220+100 will yield 3.1v, a bit lean; 3 identical resistors in a 1:2 (2 in par, one alone) would be better. on 5v, giving 3.3333. also, you're limiting the current with those values. 5v/220 = 0.02A, you want more like 0.3A at a min. to get that you'll need about 20 ohm resistors, and those will draw 1W of heat. better to use a red LED+caps or spend the $0.33 on a proper voltage regulator, like the AMS1117 or the LM317@3.3...

Comment: 220+100 gives around 3,4v, should be enough. Do i need 0,3 A on tx/rx branch when they only send and receive digital signals?

Answer (score 0):

There is an unnecessary loop in command function. Let the arduino handle the loop for you. Also it is better to try with different delay parameters, maybe you can decrease some. Here the code I offer :

```
void loop() {
  while (espmod.available()){
     String result = espmod.readStringUntil('\n');
     Serial.println("AT result : " + result);
  }  
}

void commands(String cmd, int waittime) {
  espmod.print(cmd);
  delay(waittime);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Still the same situation. It seems like it stucks after first AT command. Changing delays value also hasn't changed anything. And I prefer to print chars rather than strings, because i got full respond like here [link](http://images81.fotosik.pl/203/b690a04181ea1042.png).

Comment: After AT, have you sent AT+RST?

Comment: The snap has not got all pieces of the code above. Give a try with readStringUntil function.

Comment: [link](http://images81.fotosik.pl/203/ac887fb9c6d75df0.png) Still nothing. If it's important i flashed module using ESPFlashDownloadTool_v3.4.4 (Crystal Freq 26M,SPI Speed 40Mhz, QIO, Flash Size - 8Mbit).

Comment: Add another command after cwmode. Lets see if we got fourth espmod.available data or not. If it is, we need to change our read operation.

Comment: [link](http://images82.fotosik.pl/203/d540fddb9eee841c.png). Hmm... it's not about reading operations. Even if i put there only one AT command it will respond me with 3 lines im Serial Monitor.

Comment: Did you mind to re-write your firmware? Possibly you did :)

Comment: Yes, i did re-write the firmware. even couple of times and couple of versions. But the lastest version i installed is in the post.

Comment: What is the model of the ESP8266? Do you have any other modules to test it?

Comment: It's ESP8266 ESP-01 (Black), i have no other modules.

Comment: I have read somewhere else that older devices may have baud rate issues. Maybe you can try with 56000 115200 or etc.